# SQL: Separate column names after two inner joins

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM banhammer_bans
INNER JOIN banhammer_players AS player
    ON banhammer_bans.player_id = player.id
INNER JOIN banhammer_players AS admin
    ON banhammer_bans.creator_id = admin.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I get three `id` columns and two `name` columns from the banhammer_players table. How can I separate these so I can use them in my PHP code?

banhammer_players contains two columns, `id` and `name`. banhammer_bans has two columns (`player_id` and `creator_id`) that both match against the banhammer_players table.

Comment: Read about aliases and use table names at SELECT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all columns explicitly with an alias.

```
SELECT banhammer_bans.id as bans_id, banhammer_players as players_id, ...
FROM banhammer_bans
INNER JOIN banhammer_players AS player
    ON banhammer_bans.player_id = player.id
INNER JOIN banhammer_players AS admin
    ON banhammer_bans.creator_id = admin.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, obviously I was a bit too tired to think of the fact that I actually already had the player.* and admin.* aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the aliases in the query as:

```
   SELECT bans.id, player.name AS player_name, admin.name AS admin_name
   FROM banhammer_bans AS nans
   INNER JOIN banhammer_players AS player
   ON bans.player_id = player.id
   INNER JOIN banhammer_players AS admin
   ON bans.creator_id = admin.id
   ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

You may add as many as attributes your want in the `select` using the table aliases for ambiguous columns(same name columns in the more than one table).